# MongoDB 3.6 - Journal files are not getting cleaned up and they keep building everyday and use up a lot of disk space

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

We have recently upgraded to MongoDB 3.6 and since then we have noticed that the journal files keep building up and are not getting cleaned. Due to this, the disk usage keeps growing until there is no space left on the disk.

This issue does not occur with MongoDB 3.4. Is there anyway to enforce cleanup of journal files in MongoDB 3.6?

Update on data volumes:
We process around 148 GB of data every day. The disk space that the MongoDB data files use is around 60 GB. However, the journal files use up additional 70 GB of space everyday. Since the journal files are not getting cleaned up, the total disk space used increases by 70 GB everyday.

Comment: Hi Chandana, and welcome to dba.stackexchange. Can I ask for a clarification: what size of data are you talking about - e.g. amount per day in GB?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response! We process around 148 GB of data every day. The disk space that the MongoDB data files use is around 60 GB. However, the journal files use up additional 70 GB of space  everyday.  Since the journal files are not getting cleaned up, the total disk space used increases by 70 GB everyday.

Comment: What are your specific versions of MongoDB 3.6.x server and operating system? Also, what sort of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)?

Comment: We are using a standalone MongoDB 3.6.3 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. Also, the storage engine used is WiredTiger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue recently discovered in the MongoDB 3.6.3 release when using WiredTiger on Windows: [SERVER-33982: Unbounded growth of pre-allocated log files](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33982).

This issue will be corrected in the 3.6.4 production release, so upgrading to MongoDB 3.6.4 (or newer) when available should resolve the issue.

In the interim, possible workarounds are:

- Disable WiredTiger preallocation in 3.6.3

  - In your MongoDB config file:

    ```
    storage:
      wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
          configString: log=(prealloc=false)
    ```
  - Or, via command-line parameter:

    ```
    --wiredTigerEngineConfigString=log=(prealloc=false)
    ```
- Downgrade to MongoDB 3.6.2
- Restart your `mongod` to free up the preallocated space

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to disable WiredTiger preallocation, but I'm unable to start MongoDB after that. I tried both the config option as well as the command line option; and in both cases MongoDB did not start. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Chandana Can you check the MongoDB log file to see if there were any specific error messages on startup? Typically there should be a reason noted if `mongod` fails to start (eg. invalid or unrecognised option)

Comment: Here is an extract from the log file pertaining to this - 2018-03-26T16:20:54.872+0530 F CONTROL  [thread51] Encountered an error in PeriodicRunnerASIO: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
2018-03-26T16:20:54.872+0530 I FTDC     [serviceShutdown] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-03-26T16:20:54.876+0530 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-03-26T16:20:55.047+0530 I STORAGE  [serviceShutdown] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-03-26T16:20:55.047+0530 I CONTROL  [serviceShutdown]

Comment: In continuation to my above comment, I made some more trials and realized that the issue was with the single quote used to wrap log=(prealloc=false). When I tried the following command line argument, I was able to start MongoDB --> mongod --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\mongod.conf" --auth --wiredTigerEngineConfigString=log=(prealloc=false) --install

Comment: To summarize, the command-line alternative for the first workaround that was suggested worked well. However, setting configString in the config file has some issue (despite following the required indentation). Is there anything that I may have missed?

Comment: @Chandana I would doublecheck the indentation in the config and make sure your `mongod` is using the expected config file via `db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.config` in the `mongo` shell. Also, your config file should only have the `storage` option set once.  If the option is set correctly you should see `Engine custom option: log=(prealloc=false)` in the MongoDB log on startup. Here's a gist with an example config that should work: https://gist.github.com/stennie/4f1250ba7ad5627ccc646f04381be30b.

Comment: @Stennie, For "--wiredTigerEngineConfigString=log=(prealloc=false)", +1

Answer (score 0):

> This issue does not occur with MongoDB 3.4. Is there anyway to enforce
>   cleanup of journal files in MongoDB 3.6?

As you can limit the journal files to adding the `smallfiles=true`in `mongod.conf` configuration file. As per @mnemosyn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533019/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-journal-file-of-mongodb/25516871#25516871) and MongoDB BOL [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files).

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/manage-journaling/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747580/cleanup-of-mongo-journal-file?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: FYI, the [`smallfiles`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-mmapv1-options) configuration option is specific to the MMAPv1 storage engine.

Comment: @Stennie, Yes stennie "smallfiles=true" is applicable in case of MMAPv1 storage engine.